Is battery really needed for photoelectric effect?
In Stopping Potential of photoelectric effect, battery is inverted to calculate the potential difference at which ejection of photoelectron stops. Which means that photoelectron can even ejected without battery that's why theirs a need to invert the battery to stop photoelectron arising using certain potential difference. So why we need battery in the original experiment of photoelectric effect? Is it necessary to have battery?


Is the polarity of the battery correct in this diagram? I think the collector should have a higher potential because the electron has a negative charge.
See Photoelectric effect in Wikipedia.

That's another diagram which we have studied with the topic name stopping potential in which battery is inverted and potential difference is noted at point when the electron stops ejecting from the metal surface. That topic is not very common on internet.

Battery provides electric field and hence creates a potential difference along the plates of Cathode Ray Tube. When electrons are ejected from the metal surface they move in random direction, not in a fixed path. Due to electric field, a force is applied to electrons and hence they move in a fixed path, which increases photocurrent.
Photocurrent can be obtained without battery also, but as photoelectrons ejects at random kinetic energy and random direction less photoelectron will reach another plate. The photocurrent obtained without battery is very less
